# Get the List data including attachments and other fields data in SharePoint 2013 online using REST API

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 list with few fields like EmpId,EmployeeFirstName,EmployeeLastName,DOB and for each employee, I add image as an attachment to each row.
Now I want to pull the data of every employee with the attachment.

Is it possible to get the employee list data including attachments in one REST API call?

https://kuldeep.sharepoint.com/TQA/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%27EmployeeList%27)/Items(3)/AttachmentFiles

Thanks,
Kuldeep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, specify `AttachmentFiles` field as a projected field, using the `$select` and `$expand` query options.

For example:

```
/_api/lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=Title,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles
```

Comment: Can we get the data of the attachment file within any list?

Answer (score 0):

```
 /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list name')/items?$select=Title,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles
```

will provide FileName and ServerRelativeUrl.

Comment: Please explain your answer. It is currently viewed as a low quality post. Thanks!